# STM32F4: SD-Card using FatFs and USB fails

Tags: usb, stm32, sd

I also asked this on [SE: Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40451782/4415146)

---

In my application, I've set up a STM32F4, SD-Card and USB-CDC (all with CubeMX). 
Using a PC, I send commands to the STM32, which then does things on the SD-Card.

The commands are handled using a "communicationBuffer" (implemented by me) which waits for commands over USB, UART, ... and sets a flag, when a `\n` character was received. The main loop polls for this flag and if it is set, a parser handles the command. So far, so good.

When I send commands via UART, it works fine, and I can get a list of the files on the SD-Card or perform other access via FatFs without a problem.

The problem occurs, when I receive a command via USB-CDC. The parser works as expected, but FatFs claims `FR_NO_FILESYSTEM (13)` in `f_opendir`.
Also other FatFs commands fail with this error-code.

After one failed USB-command, commands via UART will also fail. It seems, as if the USB somehow crashes the initialized SD-Card-driver.

Any idea how I can resolve this behaviour?

---

### My USB-Implementation:

I'm using CubeMX, and therefore use the prescribed way to initialize the USB-CDC interface:

main() calls `MX_USB_DEVICE_Init(void)`.

In `usbd_conf.c` I've got:

```
void HAL_PCD_MspInit(PCD_HandleTypeDef* pcdHandle)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
  if(pcdHandle->Instance==USB_OTG_FS)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_OTG_FS_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USB_OTG_FS_MspInit 0 */

    /**USB_OTG_FS GPIO Configuration    
    PA11     ------> USB_OTG_FS_DM
    PA12     ------> USB_OTG_FS_DP 
    */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = OTG_FS_DM_Pin|OTG_FS_DP_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF10_OTG_FS;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_USB_OTG_FS_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* Peripheral interrupt init */
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(OTG_FS_IRQn, 7, 1);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(OTG_FS_IRQn);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USB_OTG_FS_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USB_OTG_FS_MspInit 1 */
  }
}
```

and the receive-process is implemented in `usbd_cdc_if.c` as follows:

```
static int8_t CDC_Receive_FS (uint8_t* Buf, uint32_t *Len)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */

    mRootObject->mUsbBuffer->fillBuffer(Buf, *Len);

    USBD_CDC_ReceivePacket(&hUsbDeviceFS);

    return (USBD_OK);

  /* USER CODE END 6 */ 
}
```

`fillBuffer` is implemented as follows (I use the same implementation for UART and USB transfer - with separate instances for the respective interfaces. `mBuf` is an instance-variable of type `std::vector<char>`):

```
void commBuf::fillBuffer(uint8_t *buf, size_t len)
{
    // Check if last fill has timed out
    if(SystemTime::getMS() - lastActionTime > timeout) {
        mBuf.clear();
    }
    lastActionTime = SystemTime::getMS();

    // Fill new content
    mBuf.insert(mBuf.end(), buf, buf + len);

    uint32_t done = 0;
    while(!done) {
        for(auto i = mBuf.end() - len, ee = mBuf.end(); i != ee; ++i) {
            if(*i == '\n') {
                newCommand = true;
                myCommand = std::string((char*) &mBuf[0],i - mBuf.begin() + 1);

                mBuf.erase(mBuf.begin(), mBuf.begin() + (i - mBuf.begin() + 1));
                break;
            }

        }
        done = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you even *try* to debug this?

Comment: @Turbo J: As I wrote, I know the error code of FatFs that occurs. Unfortunately I don't know a starting point to begin the debugging, because the same access to the SD card is working, when the command came from a UART.

Comment: Which means you have a software problem, and we have absolutely no idea how your source code looks like. There are many possible reasons for your error...

Comment: @Turbo J: OK, I will soon provide more information about the USB data processing chain.

Comment: @Turbo J: Please see my edit.

Comment: On Stack Overflow you have mentioned that you have also posted your question here. You should have mentioned it here as well that you have posted on SO

Comment: @Bence: You're right. I'll add this here, too.

Comment: I kindly invite downvoters to give feedback about the reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the problem:

In `usb_cdc_if.c` the `#define APP_RX_DATA_SIZE` was set to `4` (for some unknown reason). As this is lower than the packet size `64`, incoming packets of a larger size than 4 bytes were overwriting my memory.

It happened, that the following portion of my memory was the `FATFS* FatFs[]` pointer-list to the initialized FATFS-Filesystem structs.

So subsequently the address to this struct was overwritten, when a command of 5 or more bytes arrived.

Phew, that was a tough one.